# Sorting datagridview by priority column

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

Hi I have a datagridview that is being used to display data that is read from a XML file. 
In the XML file I have module, description, deadline and priority. I have a sort by combo box and button that I want to use to sort the datagridview data by deadline or priority.

The code below is what I currently have for the sort button. The deadline option is working nicely but I'm not sure how to order the data by priority.

For priority I have High, Medium or Low and I want high to be displayed first etc.

Any help and code examples would be appreciated.

```
string sortOption;

if (TaskTable.Rows.Count != 0) // prevents user from sorting before datagridview is filled.
{
    sortOption = sortComboBox.Text;
    switch (sortOption)
    {
        case "Deadline":
            TaskTable.Sort(TaskTable.Columns["Deadline"],
            System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            break;
        case "Priority":
            TaskTable.Sort(TaskTable.Columns["Priority"],
            System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an Enum for the priority, where High = 0, Medium = 1 and Low = 2, then use that to sort the priorities, using Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetNames methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom sorting which can be achieved by several means - see examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx